# Python requests how to send body of form-data

Tags: python, https, python-requests, http-post, google-chrome-devtools

i want to make a post request but the post request need to have header

```
content-type=multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryxzzcpJW8Y35CXWts
```

and the payload i want to send is (i copied this payload from chrome developer tools)

```
    ------WebKitFormBoundaryxzzcpJW8Y35CXWts
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="device_code"

xxxxxx
------WebKitFormBoundaryxzzcpJW8Y35CXWts
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="authorization"

bearer abcdef........
------WebKitFormBoundaryxzzcpJW8Y35CXWts--
```

i have tried to do this

```
body = {"device_code": "xxxxxx", "Authorization ": " bearer abcdef....."}
body = dumps(body)
requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=body)
```

but the request fails saying "parameter missing"

Answer (score 0):

why would you use a dumps method ? (from wich lib?)

Also you are adding a body to your request as if it was the headers.

Instead you should use the headers=, here you give it a variable headers that do not exist.

```
headers = {"device_code": "xxxxxx", "Authorization ": " bearer abcdef....."}
body = {"someting": "some json as body"}
requests.post("https://google.com", headers=headers, data=body)
```

Comment: Hello  i have just tried it without dump, it still gives same response and yes headers is a variabe i made @bastien